# Is there any way I can use BindAction() to call a function from a template class?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to implement weapon functionality in my game and right now I'm trying to bind my fire and reload events. Although I'm having a bit of trouble.

Currently, I have a template class variable called CurrentWeapon.

```
// Stores the current player weapon
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    TSubclassOf<ALTWeapon> CurrentWeapon;
```

I'm setting this variable equal to a getter function that returns the current weapon UClass* variable

```
ALTPlayer* Player;
CurrentWeapon = Player->GetCurrentWeapon();
```

The point is that CurrentWeapon != NULL

What I want to do now is use the template class to bind my fire and reload input events in my SetupPlayerInputComponent() function. I'm currently doing that like this:

```
PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Fire", IE_Pressed, this, &CurrentWeapon::OnFire);
PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Reload", IE_Pressed, this, &CurrentWeapon::OnReload);
```

This code doesn't compile because I'm not using the BindAction function parameters correctly. My main question is if there is a way I can tell the compiler to reference the class stored inside of CurrentWeapon and then access a function inside that class.

I'm getting these compilation errors:

> 'CurrentWeapon': is not a class or namespace name
>
> '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression
>
> 'UInputComponent::BindAction': no matching overloaded function found

I really sorry for my lack of correct terminology and if anyone needs me to explain further I'd be happy to!

Comment: What are your compilation errors?

Comment: @N.Shead I'm getting these compilation errors:

    'CurrentWeapon': is not a class or namespace name

    '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression

    'UInputComponent::BindAction': no matching overloaded function found